# Using the Seek Method in SQL and jumping to non-adjacent pages

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination

I'm implementing pagination using the SQL strategy called Seek method in a PostgreSql RDBMS.

All the examples that I see over the Internet are explaining how to get the next page (e.g. see [this article](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/). But I'm wondering how to implement the method to move from a page to another that is not adjacent (e.g. from page 1 to page 5) without using any offset.

Any example?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You can't. The seek method relies on knowing the last key from the adjacent page so it can then seek the next page of records from that point, If you need to allow random navigation you will need to use another method. Though maybe you could do a hybrid, eg. Leaping from page 10 to 15 would just need to count 5 pages from the anchor.

Comment: @marc_s I use postgresql

Comment: @Martin Smith how can thos method be used under the guarantee that only the following page is requested?

Answer (score 2):

A standard seek method on a table with a serial identifier can be written as:

```sql
SELECT id FROM table_with_serial_id WHERE id > prev_page_last_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT page_size;
```

Starting with `prev_page_last_id` set to 0, we can progressively advance through the table by always using the last id from the previous page.

Therefore if you want to skip to another page you could simply add `page_size` to `prev_page_last_id` to skip to the next page.

Note that this only works if you **do not have gaps in the id column** as this would cause a simple offset from the previous page.

Unfortunately in the latter there is no way to predict what the next id limit will be without going through each page, unless you want to accept the compromise of the possibility of having pages with less than `page_size`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @row_per_page INT = 100
DECLARE @page_number INT = 2

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) AS [RowNumber],*
  FROM table_name) AS T
WHERE T.[RowNumber] > (@page_number-1)*@row_per_page AND T.[RowNumber] < @page_number*@row_per_page+1
```

Comment: I am not sure how this method works, can you please elaborate?